# Is creating table entry from another table entry and copying its value good practices?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, data-integrity, rails

Lets say I have `inventory_receives` table which contain many `inventory_receive_entry` and also I have `inventory` table which contain one `inventory_receive_entry`

Then in my application `inventory_receives` instance has a method with function to loop for each `inventory_receive_entry` that it have and creates `inventory` by copying the attributes values from `inventory_receive_entry` to `inventory`

Is this a good practices?

I'm confused should I copying the value from `inventory_receive_entry` to `inventory` or should I just refer the `inventory_receive_entry` from `inventory`

my consideration about copying the value instead referring is the practicality since I not need to write complex query and such

but there are people that said about single source of truth and something like that

My schema from ruby on rails:

```
create_table "inventory_receives", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "id"
    t.bigint "supplier_id"
    t.bigint "branch_id"
  end

create_table "inventory_receives_entries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "id"
    t.bigint "inventory_receive_id", null: false
    t.bigint "product_id", null: false
    t.integer "quantity", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "expiry_date"
    t.string "barcode", default: "", null: false
    t.decimal "price", default: "0.0", null: false
    t.string "batch_code", default: "", null: false
    t.decimal "vat", default: "10.0", null: false
    t.decimal "discount", default: "0.0", null: false
  end

  create_table "inventories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "id"
    t.bigint "inventory_receive_entry_id", null: false
    t.integer "quantity", default: 0, null: false
    t.decimal "selling_price", default: "0.0", null: false
  end
```